# Recursively polling remote directory using spring integration SFTP file inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-integration

Is there way I can recursively poll a remote directory using SFTP inbound channel adapter or do I have to have multiple inbound channel adapter one for each sub directory.

My use case is that, each tenant will have a sub directory inside upload directory where they can drop csv files, our application should pool the upload directory to see if any tenant has new files then start downloading locally. Locally it will have the same folder structure.

Remote:

/upload/tenant1/*.csv

/upload/tenant2/*.csv

Local:

/upload/tenant1/*.csv

/upload/tenant2/*.csv

Comment: Can we have a code sample if you made it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `poll` not `pool`.

You can use the [sftp outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) to recursively list (`ls`) or fetch (`mget`) from a directory tree.

With `mget` you can reflect the remote directory structure locally.

Comment: Yes, I meant poll. This is exactly what I am hoping for. I will try and update you. Thank you.

Comment: It works. My case is where I will have to copy the files in sub directory only if sub directory has ready.txt file.I used mget with recursive option an I used the same concept you helped me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447460/sftp-using-spring-integration to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: @Mallikarjun can you provide us with a code sample please?